# how to get access to button in viewPager

Tags: java, android-studio, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

i would like to ask about ViewPager i had created 2 layouts in viewPager where you can slide between them. but i totaly do not know how to gain access to buttons inside of theese 2 views.

```
    Button deleteButton;
TableLayout orderTable;
TableRow order;

TableLayout preparedTable;
TableRow prepared;
TextView plus;

JSONObject rows = new JSONObject( );
int last = 0;
private ViewPager tablePager;
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sliding_panel);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    //orderTable.addView(order);

    List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new PageFragment1());
    list.add(new PageFragment2());
    tablePager = findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
    pagerAdapter = new SlidePageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),list);

    tablePager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tablePager.setCurrentItem(0);
    setMain();

    /*LayoutInflater getView = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = getView.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    plus = v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);*/
}

private void setMain() {
    View main = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, tablePager, false);

    orderTable = (TableLayout) main.findViewById(R.id.main_orders_table);
    order = (TableRow) main.findViewById(R.id.main_orders_rows);

    preparedTable = (TableLayout) main.findViewById(R.id.main_prepared_table);
    prepared = (TableRow) main.findViewById(R.id.main_prepared_rows);

    plus = (TextView) main.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    plus.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.plus:
            addOrder();
            break;
    }
}
```

so how could i call something inside of one of theese views? this does not trigered the onclicklistener.

please help thanks.

Comment: To maintain Fragment encapsulation all clicks on Buttons inside a Fragment should be handled inside the fragment

Comment: oh i see will try it tomorow... i thinked about it but did not done it thanks lets see tomorow

Comment: thanks did work rly well now i havenig tiny problem to access from 1. fragment stav in 2. fragment but that will be easier i will find way... now i know a bit how does it works. Thanks again

Comment: So to communicate between fragments/Activity there are various methods, see https://androidwave.com/passing-data-between-fragments/ I like the shared viewmodel best.

Comment: thanks but i got that one pretty fast... but still thanks... it is working now nicely... joining it to web api right now... thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should access the button from within the fragment by finding the button id

```
Button mybtn=getActivity().findViewById(yourbtnid);
```